# Manually control Intel MIC SIMD operations by intrinsics or instructions

Tags: c++, assembly, intel, simd, intel-mic

I wants to manually manage my code's the SIMD operations on MIC, and write the intrinsics below

```
_k_mask = _mm512_int2mask(0x7ff); // 0000 0111 1111 1111
_tempux2_512 = _mm512_mask_loadunpacklo_ps(_tempux2_512,_k_mask, &u_x[POSITION_INDEX_X(k,j,i-5)]);
_tempux2_512 = _mm512_mask_loadunpackhi_ps(_tempux2_512,_k_mask, &u_x[POSITION_INDEX_X(k,j,i-5)]+16);
```

And the compiler icpc gives these error message.

```
test.cpp:574: undefined reference to `_mm512_mask_extloadunpacklo_ps'
test.cpp:575: undefined reference to `_mm512_mask_extloadunpackhi_ps'
```

It will be okay to compile if I use _mm512_mask_load_ps, but my memory cannot be 64-byte-aligned so using _mm512_mask_load_ps will cause an runtime error.

Then I tried to write inline asm block manually like this

```
MOV rax,0x7ff
KMOV k1,rax
VMOVAPS zmm1 {k1}, [data_512_1]
VMOVAPS zmm2 {k1}, [data_512_2]
VMULPS  zmm3 {k1}, zmm2 zmm1
VMOVAPS [data_512_3] {k1}, zmm3
```

And the compiler icpc shows error again

```
test_simd.cpp(30): (col. 10) error: Unknown opcode KMOV in asm instruction .
test_simd.cpp(33): (col. 10) error: Syntax error ZMM1 in asm instruction vmulps.
```

I'm a beginner of assembly language,It would be really grateful if anyone can tell me why icpc didn't find the reference and how to fix it,or could recommend some materials to me. (I've read the Intel® Xeon Phi™ Coprocessor Instruction Set Architecture Reference Manual but still do not know how to write it.)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Make sure you compile with `-mmic` option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you target `AVX-512` instruction set, which is to be implemented in future desktop processors and Xeon Phi co-processors. The current generation of Xeon Phi uses a different instruction set, typically referred as `KNCNI` or `K1OM`, which is similar, but incompatible with `AVX-512` (in particular, `AVX-512` supports misaligned load instructions and `KNCNI` suggest to use a pair of load-unpack-lo + load-unpack-hi instructions for the same purpose). To compile for `KNCNI` you should use `-mmic` option for Intel Compiler (think of it as an alternative to `-m64` option, which makes compiler target `x86-64` ISA: the resulting code will not run on normal x86-64 processors and vice versa). AFAIK `AVX-512` set is not yet supported in public releases of Intel Compiler, but most likely is will use a new `-x` option.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want's to use mic offload module ,i.e. program runs on cpu but some of the parts runs on the coprocessor,_mm512_mask_loadunpacklo_ps should be the ntrinsics of instructions you mentioned. Is there any way to correctly compile it? I need the program runs on cpu either.... http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/iss/2013/compiler/cpp-lin/index.htm#GUID-21A7AB61-DE84-410A-8211-ADE9533FACE1.htm

Comment: Then you should use Xeon Phi intrinsics only when `__MIC__` is defined

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wants to use #ifndef __MIC__ but in my file it is #ifdef __MIC__. Thanks very much!!